# Expo mobile camera permission windows don't open in IOS

Tags: react-native, permissions, camera, expo

How are you, 
I am building Expo project and I need to ask camera permission.
But it don't open windows for permission

```
const { status1 } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        if (status1 !== 'granted') {
            alert('please give CAMERA permission!')
        }
        const { status2 } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        if (status2 !== 'granted') {
            alert('please give CAMERA_ROLL permission!')
        }
```

I see alert because there are no permissions,
but it don't show windows to give permissin, there is no way.

Where else can I give those permission for Expo project?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Permissions.getAsync` to `Permissions.askAsync`. See [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera) for more info.